# Comando para exibir um limite de registros em uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Supondo que uma *database* tenha uma tabela `locacoes`, qual comando SQL exibiria entre o décimo e o vigésimo registro dessa tabela, ordenados pelo campo `titulo`?

Comment: não deixa o examinador ver o stack aberto...

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM locacoes ORDER BY titulo LIMIT 9, 10;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Limit2.sql).

Não tem muitas informações mas provavelmente é isto.

Neste caso não usa o `WHERE` porque não precisa filtrar nada. Usar o `ORDER BY` para definir a ordenação e o `LIMIT 9,10` para pegar do décimo resultado e os 10 seguintes. Usa o numérico 9 para indicar o elemento inicial porque começa do 0, então se o primeiro é o 0 o décimo é o 9.

Comment: Não dá pra usar BETWEEN?

Comment: Não, o `BETWEEN` é para outra coisa. Ele é usado em filtros (no `WHERE` por exemplo). Ele se assemelha ao `IN`, desde que a lista de dados seja uma sequência continua. Por exemplo `WHERE id BETWEEN 22 AND 27` seria como fazer `WHERE id IN (22,23,24,25,26,27)`. O `LIMIT` não é bem um filtro, é uma forma de dizer quais resultados são relevantes para você. É um filtro depois que você já obteve o resultado desejado.

Comment: Depende da ordem de aplicação das condições da pergunta, @bigown aplicou: ordenar primeiro, depois pegar do 10º ao 20º desta lista, mas e se for do 10º ao 20º registros em ordem cronológica e esses apresentar ordenados pelo titulo?

Comment: @Jader é, pode ser interpretado desta forma, mas aí o "enunciado" não diz que é para pegar pelo `id`, por exemplo :) Seria entre o décimo e vigésimo baseado em que? Do jeito que vier sem critério algum? Mas acho que você matou a charada mais acima :)